# Securely importing contents of a protected js-file by using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, security, jquery, import

To import a js-file is simple... just use *>script src='file.js' type='text/javascript'>>/script>*.
But then the source code will show a direct url to the contents of the file.

The content should be executable, but not directly viewable by using source url.
**What is the best way to load the content of file.js to memory using AJAX.**

I've come to the following initial way of working (just and idea, totally flawed?):

```
function get_contents() {

      -> ajax execute PHP {copy 'file.js' to 'token.js' in tmp-directory}
      -> ajax get contents of 'tmp/token.js' and load to memory
      -> ajax execute PHP {delete 'tmp/token.js' in tmp-directory}

      return(true);    // content (ie. functions) should now be usable
      }
```

But I'm not sure if the second ajax excute is enough to now be able to succesfully call the functions.
PHP returns content, but javascript 'ajax success' may see it (and stores it) as an variable... doh!

Is this ajax success idea going to work ??
Can someone suggest a better idea ?


**Edit:**
According to initial responses this way of working is virtually and humanly impossible.
Will solve it by loading common functions the 'normal' unprotected way, and using Jerry's suggestion (see comment) for calculations that happen less often.


**Edit #2:**
Below mentioned (time consuming) problem can be solved by following next template.
Still making use of the suggested 'hidden PHP code' method.
I am making use of a buffer (or sumthing), like a Youtube video... except 'video data' is 'results from AJAX-PHP functions'.

```
AJAX request "30 cycle", "60 cycle", "300 cycle", "600 cycle"
     store result to buffer
initiate "start cycle"

function cycle() // run every second !!
{
//do stuff... no AJAX needed
//do some more stuff... like animations and small calculations

//per 30 cycle (30 seconds)
if ($cycle==30)
    {
    perform last "30 cycle" AJAX result [PHP-function set "A"]
    ... when finished: AJAX request "30 cycle"
                            store result to buffer in 'background'
    }

//per 60 cycle (1 minute)
if ($cycle==60)
    {
    perform last "60 cycle" AJAX result [PHP-function set "B"]
    ... when finished: AJAX request "60 cycle"
                            store result to buffer in 'background'
    }

//and so on....
}
```

Initial question 99% solved (-1 because of developer tools).
Thanks for commenting and suggestions.

Comment: Who are you trying to hide the js from? the client will be able to easily view it in their console no matter what method you use.

Comment: `The content should be executable, but not directly viewable by using source url.` this is not going to work. For the browser to be able to execute code, it needs to have it.

Comment: So requests to the file (function call) will be done every time ?? Instead of loading from memory ?

Comment: If you don't want the code to be visible, you will need to have your ajax invoke a function on the server and return the result, rather than loading the code into the browser.

Comment: Understood, JS is client-side. But if the file contains many functions... and lateron I will use these functions a lot... then it means that I will need a lot of ajax requests (and also split up the file into multiple unique files). It will also mean there is going to be data transfer every time I call a function and wait for the result. Is this the only way possible?

Comment: I don't think you have fully understood Jerry's answer. He means instead of having JavaScript functions do the work, you have PHP do the processing (hiding your code) and returning the results via an ajax call

Comment: I think I understood Jerry's suggestion. 1) Load common javascript functions in header and use the old-fashioned way. 2) When code should be hidden, then (instead of calling a JS-function) initiate a AJAX request to the server and perform the calculation server-side, which afterwards returns the result ready to be presented.

Comment: On thing you can do instead of having cycles is calling your ajax call again in the "success" callback of your ajax function. That way it will do the next "cycle" as soon as the next one finishes.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? As if you think this will stop people from stealing video content, it won't.. There is nothing to stop me just inserting my own code into your current JavaScript to output all results to the screen... Then regardless if you are just getting "parts" of the video I can still steal the whole thing....

Comment: True, but the procedure used to create that data is hidden in some PHP file. You only get the result (AJAX, by using developer tools), but you don't know HOW it is calculated and which functions are used (PHP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you split up your JavaScript files into lots of individual functions it would take very little work to put it all back together again.

With modern browsers even a file is "loaded into memory" you can see exactly what was loaded.

Try using the developer tools that come with browsers, you can use them to see when an Ajax call is made, exactly what was loaded in text format.

If you are mixing PHP and JavaScript then you should put anything that is sensitive in your PHP code whilst using JavaScript for your presentation of the results PHP provides.

**EDIT: as per your update, instead of doing "cycles" could you not do this?**

```
function pollAjax()
{
   $.ajax({
      -- ajax settings --
    }).success(function(data) {
        // do something with our results
        doSomething(data);
        // Fire again to get the next set of results. 
        setTimeout(function() {pollAjax()}, 10);
   });
}
```

This means you're less likely to hang the browser with 1000's of pending ajax requests It will ask for the results, when it gets them, it will ask for the next set of results.

Comment: I probably was looking for a miracle in web-coding :). Only 'problem' is that the functions are called every cycle (about every 5 seconds), so that means a lot of sending + waiting for + receiving AJAX data... which is I think a little time consuming.

Comment: Solved the time consuming question... see edit #2 in main content above.

Comment: I see. But assuming doSomething(data) means 'storing data for later usage' doesn't that translate to "buffer the complete Youtube video data"? I want it to go in steps and buffer only what is needed, ie "buffer only next 10 seconds of video". Also I don't understand your pending requests hang note. Requests only happen during initialisation (multiple, before "start cycle") and then only when timer is 30, 60, 90, 120, etc.

Comment: But what can happen is you fire one ajax request and then another one second later.. It's possible for the first one to finish after the second one.. So your "YouTube data" would be come out of sync.. That's if I understand your "runs every second" bit?

Comment: I understand your description of a possible glitch (can I call it that?) and will consider this when coding and testing. I think the out of sync problem can be solved by, if happening, temporarely pausing the cycles and showing a message (although not desired) "animation currently is paused to prevent data to get out of sync" untill data is in sync again. With 'runs every second' I mean "setInterval(cycle(), 1000);". Thanx for your responses, very much appreciated.